# outgoing call duration inappropriate android

Tags: android

Below is the code to track outgoing call duration:

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static boolean flag = false;
    static long start_time, end_time;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String phoneNumber = getResultData();
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
            // No reformatted number, use the original
            phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        }
        if (phoneNumber.equals("*0*2345#")) { // DialedNumber checking.
            // My app will bring up, so cancel the broadcast
            setResultData(null);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("extra_phone", phoneNumber);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

        if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)!=null)
        {if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
        {
            end_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long total_time = end_time - start_time;
            Toast.makeText(context, "duration :" + total_time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
                if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }}
}
```

duration of outgoing call is inappropriate, can any 1 guide me to find approximate duration of outgoing call

Answer (score 0):

Add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"></uses-permission>` to your manifent xml and than you can use the following:

```
// not on UI thread!
public String getLastCallDuration(String phoneNumber) {
        String duration = "0";
        Uri contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;// Device call log table root
        // Get device's call log sqLite table
        Cursor callLogCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                contacts, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " = ?", new String[]{phoneNumber}
                , CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC"); // Sorting the results so that the last call be first we get.
        int duration1 = callLogCursor.getColumnIndex( CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        if( callLogCursor.moveToFirst() == true ) {
            duration = callLogCursor.getString( duration1 ); // Getting the actual duration from your device.
        }
        callLogCursor.close();
    return duration;
```

Comment: I need to track duration even if the last call is deleted. As per my requirement i need to track the duration in call events. is there any appropriate formula duration?

Comment: Dear nbaroz, I tried to use ur code and its giving me the call duration of second last call. Is there a way to find last call duration? Kindly help

Comment: is it not possible to track call duration through receiver,what if someone delete call logs.any help will be appreciated,i need last call duration when outgoing call takes place